# Accessing function on scope in directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive setup as follows:

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("myDirective", function(){

    return {

       scope: {},
       link: function($scope){

           $scope.myFunction = function(){
                //Do DOM manipulation
           }

       }

    }


});
```

and in my html I simply have

```
<div my-directive>
    <a href="" ng-click="myFunction()">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

when I click "Click Me" nothing prints to the console, HOWEVER, if I remove the scope property or change it to `scope:true` then it works as expected. I know this has to do with isolate scope but I don't fully understand what's going on. I want to have an isolate scope as this is going to be a modular directive I will use in many different project.

NOTE: I'm using angular 1.4.6

**UPDATE:**
This function needs to do DOM manipulation. Which is why it's in the link function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because how `link` is being used.

Since the elements exist within the directive before it exists, those elements aren't compiled with the information inside `link`. To get what you want you need put those elements in `template` or `templateUrl` so that it can be compiled against `link`.

Here is an example:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).directive("myDirective", function() {
      return {
        scope: {},
        template: '<a href="" ng-click="myFunction()">Click Me {{value}}</a>',
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.value = 'Value here';
          scope.myFunction = function() {
            console.log('you are here.');
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div my-directive>
    <a href="" ng-click="myFunction()">Click Me {{value}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your function inside the controller of your directive.
You don't event need to use `$scope` if you declare a `controllerAs`

JS:

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("myDirective", function(){

    return {
      restrict:'E',
       scope: {},
       template:'<div><a href="" ng-click="MyCtrl.myFunction()">Click Me</a></div>',
       controllerAs:'MyCtrl',
       controller: function(){
        this.myFunction = function(){
          alert('okok');
        }
      },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){

       }

    }


});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <my-directive> </my-directive>
</body>
```